# Angular 2 Data Binding between components

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Is there a way to bind data between two components, assuming they are using two related objects.

One component is designated for filtering and the other for data results.

When checkbox is filtered data results like response, percentage, and rank can change.

Here's my stackblitz for reference, Feel free to edit my code!

[stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fya5of](http://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fya5of)

Comment: Please provide stackblitz edit link, not previewing link.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fya5of

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to solve your purpose.

(1) You can create sub component(QuestionsComponent) of Parent Component(FiltersComponent). then you pass your checkbox data in sub compoent by Input/Output method.

(2) Create one shared service. when you change in FiltersComponent ,You have to emit your data and subscribe that data in QuestionsComponent.

Thanks,

Comment: Which method is better?

Comment: In first case, when we want to pass data in sub component, then to use Input, Output method. And the second case use, when no any connection between 2 component or data pass from sub component to parent component. @Yzak